# How to import itertools in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, numpy, module

I'm running python (through IDLE, though I'm not sure what that is) on a Mac, version 3.3.2, and for some reason when I type `from itertools import *` it doesn't allow me to then use commands like `chain` and `combinations`. Additionally I can't seem to import `numpy` so I think I might have messed up the installation. Regards

#### Edit

As a minimal working example:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> chain('abc','def')
<itertools.chain object at 0x34c2130>
```

However, the output is supposed to be `a b c d e f`. So I'm not sure if I need to `print` the result?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Does `from itertools import chain` work? If it doesn't, what happens? What errors do you see? Does `import itertools` work? If it does, what does `print(itertools.__file__)` print?

Comment: Using the first suggestion, I get this message: `>>> from itertools import chain
>>> chain('abc','def')
<itertools.chain object at 0x34c2130>` and doing `print(itertools.chain)` I get `<class 'itertools.chain'>`. I apologize for how vague this is, I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Then your imports are working just fine.

Comment: Perhaps try posting a minimum working example demonstrating the error you have? That'll help us identify the problem more easily.

Comment: I've added an MWE. I'm not sure how my imports can be working fine with the  `<itertools.chain object at 0x34c2130>` message I get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you don't actually have a problem here. `itertools.chain()` does not return a list, it returns an iterable object. This is preferable as it is lazy (the values are not computed until they are needed) which is more memory-efficient.

It's worth noting if this had been an issue with importing modules, you would have had an exception, and it would have happened at the `from itertools import chain` line.

You can happily loop over it like you would any other iterable:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for item in chain('abc', 'def'):
...     print(item)
... 
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

This is the best way to use it, as it will be the most efficient. If you *need* a list (which you most likely do not), you can simply wrap the call with the `list()` built-in:

```
>>> list(chain('abc', 'def'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Ah! I'm very sorry for the confusion. I was looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html this help page, and it seemed that it would give me an output of `a b c d e f`. Many thanks

Comment: However, I wonder if you know why it does not allow me to import numpy? When I try I get this as a result: `>>> from numpy import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy import *
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

Comment: @JJR Have you installed numpy? For the Python version you are using? Either way, that's a completely different question.